# Restrict each email address or mobile number to ONE sign up only

Tags: cognito-forms

Can the email address or the mobile number that sign up user used to register be restricted to SINGLE use?

(ie the same mobile number or email address cannot be registered TWICE in same form.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

At the moment we do not support this ability, but with the [Quantity Limit](https://trello.com/c/mxxJ71Vs) feature you will be able to restrict the number of the same email address or phone number that are entered.